# Let Batch Script select file in disk?

Tags: batch-file

I have a drive with lots of text files that are in folders. I'm trying to make a batch file that appends some text into the last part of every file like such:

```
    :LOOP
    [I need the batch file to set a file name as %file% here]
    echo Correct>>%file%
    goto LOOP
```

How do I make the batch file select a file name to set as %file%? *If* possible please try not to use DELAYEDEXPANSION. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should append the message to the end of every .txt file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir *.txt /b /s /a-d ') do >>"%%a" echo Correct
```

Comment: It works only for the text files at the root of the disk (the batch file is there too), but those files in folders are not edited...

Comment: I added the `/s` to process subdirectories as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a One-Liner. You don't even need the loop (that's what `for` does for you):

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do @echo Correct>>"%%i"
```

Comment: I've created a folder and mapped it using subst, but testing this code  on cmd gave me %%i was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Hz.tiang to use it on commandline use asingle percent-sign `%i` instead of double `%%i` (double for use in Batch files)

Comment: I think we had this discussion before Stephen, with `for` processing files multiple times, and I'm getting old and past it.  Your code works fine that way - it's when new files matching the filespec are created that it can happen. Mea Culpa.

Comment: @foxidrive: don't mind - it didn't keep me from sleeping well ^^